# How to set 12 hour clock format for the entire iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, datetime

I would like to set the 12 hour clock format for my entire iPhone application irrespective of whether the user has set the iPhone device clock format to 12 hrs or 24 hrs.
Please advise as to how this can be achieved.

Comment: Are you using NSDateFormatter?

Comment: Yes, I am using NSDateFormatter to display date and time throughout the application. I am setting the date format of the formatter as [dateFormatterForDisplay setDateFormat:@"EEE MM/dd - h:mm a"];
This displays correctly if the device clock format is 12 hours. But if it is 24 hr format, then the time in the application is displayed sans am/pm and in 24 hour format (which is what i want to avoid).

Comment: As a user of 24hr format - I would want all times to be 24hr - are you trying to stop that?

Comment: @Mark - I get your point. But this is a requirement from someone else.  So I am still looking to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the locale of my NSDateFormatter object to en_US and that does the trick for presenting the time in 12 hour format.

```
NSLocale *uslocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatterForDisplay setLocale:uslocale];
[uslocale release];
```

Comment: how could I use 24 hours always then? Thanks.